# SQL: How to get all rows using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given this example table. I would like to get all rows that sum of debts > 1000.

```
TABLE_1

ID   NAME        DEBT
1    Daniel      1000
2    Daniel      10    
3    Xavier      500
4    Ricardo     600
5    Ricardo     300
6    Eduardo     2000
7    Eduardo     1000
```

The result table should be:

```
RESULT

ID   NAME        DEBT
1    Daniel      1000
2    Daniel      10
6    Eduardo     2000
7    Eduardo     1000
```

This is because Daniel debt is 1010 so is greather than 1000. Same for Eduardo which debt is 3000. The important result are the IDs. How could I make this query in SQL?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*    -- or whatever columns you want
from (select t.*,
             sum(debt) over (partition by name) as sum_debt
      from t
     ) t
where sum_debt > 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested query.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME IN ( SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY NAME HAVING SUM(DEBT)>1000);
```